# how to extract data/figure from GUI Matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, figure

I have this matlab GUI (not made by me of course), and I have been looking everywhere for almost about a week on how I can possibly extract the figures from it to no success. I am at my wits end and was wondering if any one could help?

I want to be able to copy the figure (and save to desktop to extract data from after), or copy the data in a form of a matrix that I can manipulate and save. I thought I'd put the GUI here in case anyone wants to give it a shot and help (I'd be willing to paypal someone cash if they can help me!):

http://www.mediafire.com/?vqxymayztac3bvp

This is how you produce the image:

1. open spec_gui
2. click file, open, select FocusedInfinity.mat
3. press "Calculate"
4. push buttons

   A."XY Profile" & "DimSum" with Elem slider set to "1"

   B."XY Profile" & "DimSum" with Elem slider set to "5"
5. the top window will display an image:

[image]

Comment: If you have the `*.mat`-file - don't you have all the data you need? Why extract it from plots in a GUI?

Comment: The .mat file is just a list of variables that are inputed into the GUI. The GUI does the calculation and creates the figure after.

Comment: A GUI is just a [Graphical User Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface). It will just call functions that manipulate the data for you (and eventually plot them). You have all the files - you don't need to extract anything from the GUI, just understand the underlying functions.

Comment: Yes, I understand that...but I am a matlab beginner (I started a little more than a week ago). The GUI is pretty darn complicated and like I said, I've been trying for a week or so. At this point of time, I feel like I need some outside help. Also, work/research waits for no one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd attack this.

1. Open the figure in GUIDE.
   [image: Right Click and GUIDE]
2. That opens the GUIDE editor like so:
   [image: GUIDE]
3. Right click on the Calculate button and look at the `Property Inspector`.
   [image: Right Click Properties]
4. Then you can look at the properties, look for `Callbacks` of any type that are defined.
   [image: Inspector]
5. Click the `Callback` worksheet with a pencil icon and it brings up the editor with `spec_gui.m` and the `calcbtn_Callback`.

   ```
   % --- Executes on button press in calcbtn.
   function calcbtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

   h=handles.param;
   h.nu=linspace(h.extfreq(1),h.extfreq(2),h.n_freq);
   [handles.pList,handles.data]=speccalc('nfile','temp','spec',h.spec, ...
           'gamma',h.gamma,'ng',h.n_mode,'nu',h.nu,'np',h.n_r,'silent',1, ...
           'dim',1:h.n_dim,'m',h.m','cart',h.cart);
   handles.file='temp.mat';
   handles=update_data(hObject, [], handles);
   update(hObject, [], handles);
   ```

This is what calculates the figure, you can repeat this process to see what the "XY Profile" & "DimSum" and Elem slider callbacks are and what they do.  It'll be a little bit of work, but you'll get it.  Otherwise SO is here to help.  :-)

Comment: So, I did try this method before but I got pretty confused. With simpler codes, I was able to execute every line in the MATLAB command line.

With this code though (like the one you posted), none of the variables are listed (I believe they are embedded in the GUI code). Any ideas?

Comment: You're right, the function has its own [workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html) that's separate from the base workspace. This keeps data between the base and a function separate. That said, add a [`keyboard`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html) call before the end of the function and MATLAB will halt execution and let you examine the function workspace.

Comment: Ok so I have been using the Keyboard function to get to the line of code right as the "figure" is being calculated. But, now I am having trouble extracting the data still. I have tried:gco,gcf guidata...but to no success :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK I DID IT!

With a combo of what MACDUFF and DANGKHOA (thanks so much guys) said and a few hours later!

1. I found out which line in the code the buttons are being utilized (ie what MAC DUFF said)
2. I put a "keyboard" right after, but before the end of the code (ie what DAN KHOA said)
3. When I started the GUI and calculation and pressed the button the matlab script displayed "k"
4. I typed in figure
5. then "imagesc(im)", which "im" was what the GUI was saving the image data as.

BINGO! Thanks guys...so much work sigh[image]