# In a MATLAB GUI, extract coordinates by clicking inside a plot and display it

Tags: matlab, user-interface, coordinates, extract, matlab-guide

I'm pretty new to MATLAB, I have looked everywhere for a solution to this problem :

Let's use this GUI for example :

[image: gui image]

How can I, by clicking somewhere inside the plot, get to display the `x` coordinate in the text box ?

Here's the code that I tried in the GUI code, but couldn't get it to work :

```
function axes1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

[x y] = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');

set(handles.edit1,'string', num2str(x));

guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Comment: Does [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237381/how-to-extract-data-figure-from-gui-matlab) help?

Comment: Not really, the two problems aren't really related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Oh, misread the question. I pushed my original answer to the bottom of the post. It might still be useful. Here you go:

```
function axes1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

[x y] = eventdata;

set(handles.edit1,'string', num2str(x));

guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Note, I've seen instances where eventdata just doesn't work. If you try to use it and it's empty, then let me know and I'll try to walk you through doing it using a custom datacursormode tooltip callback function, which is significantly more complex, but doable.

Original:

```
datacursormode on
```

For additional information see [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html) page. I've done a lot of work with custom data cursor mode functions, and plot-clicky things, so if you have more specfic questions, feel free to ask.